# Fluid layout for Windows Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, fluid-layout

I want to have fluid layout for my view in a windows store app.

In a new page template you have a Grid which has a row set to fill the screen after the title at the top of the page.

So I have my content to enter into this grid row. My content is going to be a mixture of controls (images, text, vertical listview, maybe another gridview) but it isn't a single grouped collection that I can bind to a single gridview.

The point I'm trying to make is that I want my horizontal width to be more than that of the page, yet I want to size things fluidly which means relative to a single page height / width.

Ideally I don't want to have to specify hard coded widths for controls as I want this layout to work for as many different screen resolutions as possible. That being said, I imagine I will use Min / MaxWidth and heights to make sure items aren't too big or too small.

What approach should I take?

**EDIT**
Hopefully the following image would better describe what I mean.

[image]

The first image shows a (grouped) gridview that automatically will expand horizontally as it requires. This would work well but the controls I want to add are not grouped / related to each other.

The second image is what I am trying to do, which is to have a number of unrelated controls in a window but have them scroll off the side of the page horizontally. I can do this if I give each control a fixed width but I want to try and make it more flexible than that if possible (using min / maxWidth but not fixed values for the widths themselves).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use star values in grid. Like:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
...
```

and use `ViewBox` as the top container. ViewBox will scale all the content to fill the available size.

Comment: Won't the ViewBox just scale to the width of the page? I was looking to have the content scroll off the side of the page (see my edit above).

Comment: So, Horizontal ScrollViewer is the solution.

Comment: OK, thanks that does seem to be the answer I guess. I was still hoping to use relative sizing for everything in the ScrollViewer, would it seem correct to base my control sizes upon the layoutRoot grid width and use converters to proportion them accordingly?

Comment: This looks a bit hard to do. Depending how do you want to scale the controls inside. I see that you want to scale some controls to all height and other not.